# create drill down radar/spider chart with d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, drilldown, radar-chart

I am trying to create a radar chart/spider chart with d3.js and followed the demo given here 
[Radar chart](http://bl.ocks.org/nbremer/6506614)

Now I want to add drill down option to it. like if clicked on any point it will animate and redraw the chart with new data.

I am not able to find any reference on the web.Please help

Comment: [This radar-chart implementation](https://github.com/alangrafu/radar-chart-d3) might help but I think you should clarify what should happen when the radar chart "drills down" because you could go about visualizing the drill down in many ways.

Comment: I had a look of the example you mentioned.but It does not shows how to drill down. I want drill down like http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-drilldown but in radial/spider chart.

Answer (score 0):

There's a very good alternative if you are fine with using Highcharts.This should help http://jsfiddle.net/t8Lgode0/

`chart: {
        polar: true,
        type: 'column'
    },`